# Sending nested object via post request

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, express, query-string

I'm running this little node express server, which is supposed to check if the voucher is valid later and then send an answer back to the client

this is my code

```
app.post('/voucher', function (request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'authorization, content-type');
      if ( request.method === 'OPTIONS' ) {
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end();
        return;
      }
    console.log(request)
    let results;
    let body = [];
        request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
      }).on('end', function() {
        results = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        // results = JSON.parse(results);

        console.log('#### CHECKING VOUCHER ####', results)
        let success = {success: true, voucher: {name: results,
                                    xxx: 10}}
        success = qs.escape(JSON.stringify(success))

        response.end(success)

      } )
    }
  );
```

It is obviously just an example and the actual check is not implemented yet. So far so good.

Now on the client side where I work with REACT, I can not seem to decode the string I just send there.

there I'm doing this

```
var voucherchecker = $.post('http://localhost:8080/voucher', code , function(res) {   

  console.log(res)
  let x = JSON.parse(res)
  console.log(x)
  console.log(qs.unescape(x))
```

It gives me the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0

When I do it the other way arround

```
      let x = qs.unescape(res)
  console.log(x)
  console.log(JSON.parse(x))
```

Than it tells me

> Uncaught TypeError: _querystring2.default.unescape is not a function

Maybe you can help me? I don't know what the issue is here. Thank you.

**Also another question on this behalf**, since I'm only a beginner. Is there smarter ways to do such things than I'm doing it now? I have react which renders on the client and I have a mini express server which interacts a few times with it during the payment process.
The both run on different ports.

What would be the standard way or best practice to do such things?

Comment: What will happen if you remove the first character in "res" and then do JSON.parse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit perplexed as to why your backend code has so much going on in the request.
Since you asked for if there is a different way to write this, I will share with you how I would write it.

#### Server

It seems that you want your requests to enable CORS, it also seems that you originally wanted to parse a JSON in your request body.

This is how I would recommend you re-write your endpoint

POST /voucher to take a request with body JSON

```
{
  code: "xxxxx"
}
```

and respond with

```
{
  success: true, 
  voucher: {
    name: results,
    xxx: 10
  }
}
```

I would recommend you use express's middleware feature as you will probably use CORS and parse JSON in most your requests so in your project I would.

```
npm install body-parser
npm install cors
```

then in your app initialization

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json you can choose to just pars raw text as well
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// this will set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * similar for all response headers
app.use(cors())
```

You can read more about [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) in their respective repos, if you don't want to use them I would still recommend you use your own middleware in order to reduse future redundancy in your code.

So far this will substitute this part of your code

```
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'authorization, content-type');
  if ( request.method === 'OPTIONS' ) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end();
    return;
  }
console.log(request)
let results;
let body = [];
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', function() {
    results = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    // results = JSON.parse(results);
```

Now your route definition can just be

```
app.post('/voucher', function (request, response) {
  var result = request.body.code // added by body-parser
  console.log('#### CHECKING VOUCHER ####', result)
  // express 4+ is smart enough to send this as json
  response.status(200).send({
    success: true,
    voucher: {
      name: results,
      xxx: 10
    }
  })
})
```

#### Client

your client side can then be, assuming `$` is jquery's post function

```
var body = {
  code: code
}
$.post('http://localhost:8080/voucher', body).then(function(res) {   
   console.log(res)
   console.log(res.data)
   return res.data
})
```

Comment: Hej Amr, this is perfect.

But in general would you do it that way? would send a json between the server and the client like this? Is that the best practice way to do it or how would you do it?

Comment: For RESTful API endpoints JSON is the most widely used format, I think people may vary in the protocol choice but it is safe to say that JSON is the most dominant data structure. As for how the JSON should be structured as long as you are consistent it is fine. You can of course subscribe to using a standard like [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org/)

Comment: If I now send a nested object through that post request on the server it comes like this:

  `'orders[0][label1]': 'blabla',
  'orders[0][label2]': 'blablasdas',
  'orders[0][label3]': 'Home',`

How do I change it to a nested object, now it thinks its a string